# Index and length should refer to a location within the sequence

Tags: vb.net

I need to break a variable to get the value of the database. Today my full return would be "2017-09-15T14: 01: 46" I only need 2017-09-15 and 14:01, I tried to do

.Substring (0.10) for the date and worked, already for the time I tried Substring (11,16) and the error that is in the title of the question occurs.

Comment: The handy-dandy `DateTime` type would allow you to get the date and time portions easily.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always have the capital T in your result string

```
dim xValue as string = "2017-09-15T14: 01: 46"
dim xStr() as string = xValue.split("T")
dim xDate as string = ""
dim xTime as string = ""

if xstr.count>0 then
  xDate = xStr(0)
  xTime = xStr(1)
end if
```

or

```
dim xValue as string = "2017-09-15T14: 01: 46"
dim xDate as string = strings.left(xValue, 10)
dim xTime as string = strings.mid(xValue, 12)
```

Comment: If you are using the second options you want to put this in a try catch block to avoid your app crashing for a string not compatible or not long enougth or whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments to the function Substring are wrong.

The second argument to the function Substring (in your case 16) needs to be the amount of letters that the function will return and NOT the index it needs to end in.

It will work with something like Substring(11, 5), where the 5 is the length of the returned substring.

```
    Dim temp_date As String = "2017-09-15T14: 01: 46"
    Dim main_date As String = temp_date.Substring(0, 10)
    Dim main_time As String = temp_date.Substring(11, 6)
```

OR

a better approach using the datetime object proposed by AustinS90 (this will support alot of time formatted strings):

```
    Dim temp_date As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2017-09-15T14: 01: 46")
    Dim main_date As String = temp_date.Year() & "-" & temp_date.Month() & "-" & temp_date.Day
    Dim main_time As String = temp_date.Hour & ":" & temp_date.Minute
```

Answer (score 0):

So with VB.NET, you can use the DateTime method. From the DateTime, you can do something like DateTime.Date or DateTime.ToShortDateString for just the date and DateTime.ToShortTimeString for the time.